# Why form lost bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm learning MVC and I'm making contact form by first code.
Could someone of you explain me why the message area is smaller than title editor and why it lost the bootstrap css?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="wyslij" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: Any reason why you're using an editor template instead of a text box for your title?

Comment: it's automatically generated by scaffolding, I just tried to change the part with message to have text area not editor

Comment: Are you able to solve your problem, please check my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated Fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/DWy02w

**Output :**

[image]

**HTML :**

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container col-md-10">
            @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">           
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.title,  new { @class = "form-control" } )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.message,  new { @class = "form-control" } )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="wyslij" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>  
                <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Model :**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public string title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string message
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK your usage of bootstrap grid classes (col-*) is wrong. Probably you should wrap your form in in a row and column, like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
    ...
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

As for width of message textarea, I think it is because of styles in Site.css. You can try to remove the link to Site.css and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a text box instead of an editor template. Replace this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

With this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```